# Cannot use PAM authent for SMTP connection

Tags: pam, exim

I'm trying to setup PAM authentification for SMTP client connection. So to authent for SMTP to send mail, using the same as the login to the host.

The log says:

```
2011-04-28 20:19:31 plain_pam authenticator failed for xxxx ([x.x.x.x]) [x.x.x.x]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=user)
2011-04-28 20:19:33 login_pam authenticator failed for xxxx ([x.x.x.x]) [x.x.x.x]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=user)
```

/etc/pam.d/exim:

```
auth            required       pam_unix.so
account         required       pam_permit.so
session         required       pam_permit.so
```

Any hints to look or activate some trace info to see what is failing ?

Answer (score 2):

As what user does exim run and can that user read `/etc/pam.d/exim` and `/etc/shadow` (assuming your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` has `files` for `passwd` and `shadow`).

Comment: Ok, it was the /etc/shadow file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On a Debian machine, in my case I had to add exim4 user to the `shadow` group.

```
usermod -a -G shadow Debian-exim
```

> PAM: On Debian systems the PAM modules run as the same user as the
>   calling program, so they cannot do anything you could not do yourself,
>   and in particular cannot access /etc/shadow unless the user is in
>   group shadow. - If you want to use /etc/shadow for Exim's SMTP AUTH
>   you will need to run exim as group shadow. Only exim4-daemon-heavy is
>   linked against libpam. We suggest using saslauthd instead.

http://lira.no-ip.org:8080/doc/exim4-base/README.Debian.html